Set specific logback.xml file with -Dlogback.configurationFile when logback.xml is just in .war package
I have one logback.xml file and I want to split it per environment e.g dev, prod.
I have found: How to use multiple configurations with logback in a single project?
and I see that I can do it via -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml. That's great, but how to do it in good manner?
I have spring application where logback-env.xml is under /src/main/resources. After deployment I just can find it in /deployedApp/users/myapp/com.myapp/10.0-SNAPSHOT/war/app/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml.
I also have a script which is setting all properties for tomcat and I can add it like this:
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dlogback.configurationFile=/deployedApp/users/myapp/com.myapp/10.0-SNAPSHOT/war/app/WEB-INF/classes/logback-dev.xml"

unfortunately it doesn't make sense for me because let's say that I will do some project structure change and will remove users from path or some other change. This will blow up.
What is the best way to specify with -Dlogback.configurationFile which logback-env.xml should be taken?
How to pass path (which is changing during deployment) to logback.xml file to tomcat start script instead of hardcoding it?

project tree
demo1
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        ....
        ├── resources
        │   ├── application.properties
        │   └── logback.xml
        └── webapp
        ... 

application.properties
logging.config=${LOG_FILE_PATH:classpath:logback.xml}
# export LOG_FILE_PATH=/my-conf-path/logback.xml

Build War
mvn clean package

put war to Tomcat

put demo1.war to Tomcat/webapps

Test 1 - Default

startup Tomcat

./startup.sh

Because the environment variable LOG_FILE_PATH has not been set, it will use the default value: classpath:logback.xml
demo1.war will use
apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo1/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml


shutdown tomcat

./shutdown.sh

Test 2 - Use Environment Variable

Prepare another logback.xml in /your-path/conf/logback.xml

startup Tomcat with Environment Variable


export LOG_FILE_PATH=/your-path/conf/logback.xml

./startup.sh


Use the same war file.

If the environment variable (LOG_FILE_PATH) is not set, use logback.xml included in war.


classpath:logback.xml mapping to

Source: src/main/resources/logback.xml
Runtime: Tomcat/webapps/demo1/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml


If environment variables (LOG_FILE_PATH) are set, reference logback.xml according to the specified path.

export LOG_FILE_PATH=/your-path/conf/logback.xml

./startup.sh

